# Book On Making /rdb

Tags: linux, database, awk, rdbms

I was told once there is a book that shows you how to make a database from scratch using sed, awk, and the Linux filesystem. I thought I had the name, but now I cannot find it. What is this book called?

Edit: 
My understanding is this book was meant for learning how databases work, and how to build your own entirely from scratch using awk and the filesystem. From how it was explained, you could build your own version of /rdb, then when you finished you could just use /rdb itself, but now you'd know how it was made.

So, at the end of the book, you'd have almost completely remade /rdb yourself.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? It's objective, has an answer, and simple. If I can't ask this here due to some rules, where can I ask it?

Comment: I suspect because it's not clear what you're asking. What does it mean to "make a database"? I can create a flat file and write some scripts to operate on it and voila I have a database (a collection of data + software to manage it). Is that what you want? There are existing UNIX database tools like `unity` - is that what you're asking for a book on? Are any of the databases listed at http://linuxfinances.info/info/rdbmsmisclinux.html what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it "Unix Relational Database Management: Application Development in the Unix Environment (/RDB)" http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=013938622X/cbbrownecompu-20/ ?

Comment: I looked into that, and it looks like that just is a reference on /rdb itself, rather than a guide to remake /rdb

Comment: I added tags for rdb and rdbms to your question, maybe that'll attract someone who knows something about this.

Comment: Actually, this might be the book, I confused this with the /rdb manual I found. I'll try to get a copy of it. Thanks!